# Cannot find module vite.js

Tags: node.js, npm, vite, npm-run

I'm working on a React project using Vite. I have installed all the packages but when I enter `npm run dev` it shows me an error:

> Express\passop\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1152
> throw err;
> ^
>
> ```
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\HP\Downloads\vite\bin\vite.js'
>     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
>     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
>     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
>   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   requireStack: []
> }
> ```

I want to run in the localhost.

Comment: The npm install was succeed?